# UV coordinates are locked from -10 to 10?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to make a face which has a texture loop quite a few times. However, it seems that UV coordinates can't be manually edited using the UV vertex fields, outside the range [-10, 10]. This seems like an arbitrary restriction, especially given that right-clicking and dragging the vertex in the editor allows the vertex to be moved outside this range.

Have I accidentally enabled something without noticing it? Is there a way to disable this clamping?

Edit: I should specify that the range is using the normalized mode, not pixel coordinates.

Comment: to me also stops at -10, 10 if you just use the slider field but not if moved by hand. guess that is regular behavior. wouldn't know why

Answer (score 1):

In code most UI widgets such as sliders, number fields etc ask you to set min and max values.
In some cases this can be relevant to how the widget behaves (for example, sliders with large ranges are harder to slide to specific value due to display precision).
In this case the limits are most likely arbitrary.

For things like texture looping or tiling, normally this is done by using the vector mapping node in the materials edit to scale the UV coordinates, rather than in the original coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around it by sliding the coordinate to a number larger than I wanted (i.e 33), then I was able to manually edit the number down to 32.